# How to define an object inside the render part?

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering

In my render code I create a map in order to use it with the conditional rendering of React but I get an undefined error because it can't find it. Is it a way to fix that ?

```
render(){
    if(this.state.jsondata.prediction2){
        const occurrenceMap2 = Object.values(this.state.jsondata.prediction2).reduce((finalMap, item) => {
            finalMap[item] = ++finalMap[item] || 1;   
            return finalMap;
        } , {})
    }
...

   {this.state.jsondata.prediction2 &&
     <p> occurrenceMap2[0] </p>
   }
}
```

Comment: don't use if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the if statement and declare occurrenceMap2 once and set a default value if `this.state.jsondata.prediction2` doesn't a have a value.

```
const occurrenceMap2 = this.state.jsondata.prediction2 && Object.values(this.state.jsondata.prediction2).reduce((finalMap, item) => {
  finalMap[item] = ++finalMap[item] || 1;   
  return finalMap;
} , {}) || []; // set a default value here
```

Answer (score 1):

`const` and `let` in javascript are block-scoped, which means that they only exist in the block in which you define them. Thats why in this case, without any relation to React, you cant access `occurenceMap2` from outside the `if` statement. Try this instead:

```
    let occurrenceMap2 = [];
    if(this.state.jsondata.prediction2){
        occurrenceMap2 = Object.values(this.state.jsondata.prediction2).reduce((finalMap, item) => {
            finalMap[item] = ++finalMap[item] || 1;   
            return finalMap;
        } , {})
    }
...

   {this.state.jsondata.prediction2 &&
     <p> occurrenceMap2[0] </p>
   }
}
```

Comment: it works like a charm ! Thank you very much and yes I forgot about the block-scoped, I already had a similar issue before. Thank you